# Swiper Js active thumb not sync with with active slide in react js

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am trying to create a a slider with thumb with swiper js in React. I want to create a slider like this
one [codepen link](https://codepen.io/ezra_siton/pen/XWrBzMp) from this one [official codesandbox of swiper js](https://codesandbox.io/s/fbs9e8?file=/src/App.jsx).

I am not able to do so. Is there any module or events to do so?
There is a slight difference in that the navigation button will be in the thumb section.

My little effort link [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-ioana-0tofhj?file=/src/App.js).

```
const Reviews = () => {
     const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);
     return (
         <Container Class='reviews'>
             <Swiper
                 style={{
                     "--swiper-navigation-color": "#fff",
                     "--swiper-pagination-color": "#fff",
                 }}
                 onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
                 loop={true}
                 centeredSlides={true}
                 slidesPerView={5}
                 spaceBetween={10}
                 navigation={true}
                 modules={[Navigation, Thumbs]}
                 watchSlidesProgress={true}
                 slideToClickedSlide={true}
                 watchSlidesVisibility={true}
                 className="mySwiper2"
             >
                 <SwiperSlide>
                     <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                 </SwiperSlide>
                 {........}
                 <SwiperSlide>
                     <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
                 </SwiperSlide>
             </Swiper>
             <Swiper
                 thumbs={{swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null}}
                 loop={true}
                 spaceBetween={10}
                 centeredSlides={true}
                 freeMode={true}
                 navigation={true}
                 modules={[ Navigation, Thumbs]}
                 className="mySwiper"
            >
                <SwiperSlide>
                    <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
                </SwiperSlide>
                {........}
               <SwiperSlide>
                   <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg" />
               </SwiperSlide>
           </Swiper>
       </Container>
   )
}
```